# Spark/Yarn: FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, filenotfoundexception

I am runnig the following code in spark.

```
scala>import com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlInputFormat
scala>import org.apache.hadoop.io._
scala>sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY,"<mytag>")
scala>sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY,"</mytag>")
scala>sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(XmlInputFormat.ENCODING_KEY,"utf-8")
scala>val record1 = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("file:///home/myuser/myfile.xml", classOf[XmlInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text])
```

When I run it by setting master to local it works fine.

```
spark2-shell --jars spark-xml_2.10-0.4.1.jar --master local[*]
```

But when I try to run it in `yarn` it return `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/myuser/myfile.xml does not exist`.

```
spark2-shell --jars spark-xml_2.10-0.4.1.jar --master yarn
```

I tried to add `--deply-mode` as `client` and `cluster` but it didn't work.

Comment: When running a job in spark using --deploy-mode, keep the jar file in the same location in all the nodes. Since, the job will be executed in parallel, it'll search for the jar, in all the nodes, in your case it'll not be present in other that the machine you ran the command. Or try to keep the jar in HDFS and passing the HDFS location of jar as argument to the --jars.

Comment: You get FileNotFoundException, but which file is not found? xml or jar?

Comment: I added the jar file to hdfs and gave the hdfs path: spark2-shell --jars hdfs:/user/myuser/spark-xml_2.10-0.4.1.jar --master yarn --deploy-mode client. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I get FileNotFoundException on the xml file. Not jar. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Th file `file:///home/myuser/myfile.xml"` seems only accessible on your driver, but not on your executors. You should either
A)  manually the file on HDFS and read from there

or B) use `--files` option of spark2-shell which does upload the file to HDFS for you:

```
spark2-shell --files /home/myuser/myfile.xml --jars spark-xml_2.10-0.4.1.jar --master yar
```

and then

```
val record1 = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("myfile.xml"), classOf[XmlInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used --files option but when I assign file to record1 I am getting 'error: org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.type does not take parameters'. Do I need to import any class?

Comment: I think I need to add 'get' in the command, org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("myfile.xml"). The current error is gone but it says there is no such file in hdfs. I think --files option is not uploading my file. Also is there no way to access local files without uploading them to hdfs while using yarn?

Comment: @HSP you should see in the logs whether the file is uploaded or not

Comment: I uploaded the file into hdfs using copyFromLocal command. I checked and the file is present in hdfs. But it is showing 'input path does not exist'.